# Xml parsing of images in flutter

Tags: xml, parsing, flutter, rss, cdata

I wanna parse an image and use it in an application. But what I really need is the src link which is in the image tag AND to also get the the CDATA in the linik tag..

This is the rss feed:

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>E! Online (US) - Top Stories</title>
<link>https://www.eonline.com/</link>
<category>(US) - Top Stories</category>
<description>
News from across the show-biz spectrum-TV, movies, music and celebrities
</description>
<language>en-us</language>
<ttl>10</ttl>
<pubDate>Mon, 13 Apr 2020 00:42:22 GMT</pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>Mon, 13 Apr 2020 00:42:22 GMT</lastBuildDate>
<image>
<title>E! Online (US) - Top Stories</title>
<width>120</width>
<height>60</height>
<link>https://www.eonline.com/</link>
<url>
https://images.eonline.com/eol_images/Entire_Site/2018223/rs_125x40-180323122205-EGoogleNews.png
</url>
</image>
<copyright>
© 2020 E! Entertainment Television, Inc. All rights reserved., https://www.eonline.com/about/copyright/index.jsp
</copyright>
<item>
<title>
Jennifer Lopez and Diddy Reunite on Instagram Live During His Dance-a-Thon Fundraiser
</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
https://www.eonline.com/news/1140003/jennifer-lopez-and-diddy-reunite-on-instagram-live-during-his-dance-a-thon-fundraiser?cmpid=rss-000000-rssfeed-365-topstories&utm_source=eonline&utm_medium=rssfeeds&utm_campaign=rss_topstories
]]>
</link>
<description>
<img src="https://images.eonline.com/resize/66/66//eol_images/Entire_Site/201742//rs_600x600-170502090801-600-jennifer-lopez-diddy-met-gala-alex-rodriguez.jpg" height="66" width="66" border="0" alt="Jennifer Lopez, Sean Diddy Combs, MET Gala Then and Now" align="left" hspace="5" />Who's got better dance moves: Jennifer Lopez or Sean "Diddy" Combs? On Sunday, Diddy asked his fellow celeb friends to get up and dance for a cause. Posting on Instagram,...<br clear="all" />
</description>
<pubDate>Mon, 13 Apr 2020 00:42:22 GMT</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">b1140003</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>
Tiger King Aftershow Episode: 5 of the Biggest Bombshells
</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
https://www.eonline.com/news/1139997/tiger-king-aftershow-episode-5-of-the-biggest-bombshells?cmpid=rss-000000-rssfeed-365-topstories&utm_source=eonline&utm_medium=rssfeeds&utm_campaign=rss_topstories
]]>
</link>
<description>
<img src="https://images.eonline.com/resize/66/66//eol_images/Entire_Site/2020230//rs_600x600-200330065841-600-5-tiger-king-ch-033020.jpg" height="66" width="66" border="0" alt="Tiger King" align="left" hspace="5" />Hey all you cool cats and kittens... Netflix is giving the fans what they want: another Tiger King episode. That's right, the streaming service knew people were craving more...<br clear="all" />
</description>
<pubDate>Mon, 13 Apr 2020 00:04:21 GMT</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">b1139997</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>
Mariah Carey Blesses Us on Easter With Virtual Performances of Her Emancipation of Mimi Singles
</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
https://www.eonline.com/news/1139991/mariah-carey-blesses-us-on-easter-with-virtual-performances-of-her-emancipation-of-mimi-singles?cmpid=rss-000000-rssfeed-365-topstories&utm_source=eonline&utm_medium=rssfeeds&utm_campaign=rss_topstories
]]>
</link>
<description>
<img src="https://images.eonline.com/resize/66/66//eol_images/Entire_Site/2020312//rs_600x600-200412134740-600_Mariah_Carey_MP_4.12.20.jpg" height="66" width="66" border="0" alt="Mariah Carey, Instagram" align="left" hspace="5" />Mariah Carey is not only celebrating Easter Sunday this weekend but she's also celebrating the 15th anniversary of one of her most iconic albums, The Emancipation of Mimi. The...<br clear="all" />
</description>
<pubDate>Sun, 12 Apr 2020 22:27:45 GMT</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">b1139991</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>
Hilary Duff Says Goodbye to Her Blonde Hair and Reveals an Epic New Look
</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
https://www.eonline.com/news/1139985/hilary-duff-says-goodbye-to-her-blonde-hair-and-reveals-an-epic-new-look?cmpid=rss-000000-rssfeed-365-topstories&utm_source=eonline&utm_medium=rssfeeds&utm_campaign=rss_topstories
]]>
</link>
<description>
<img src="https://images.eonline.com/resize/66/66//eol_images/Entire_Site/2019913//rs_600x600-191013094707-600-hilary-duff.cm.101319.jpg" height="66" width="66" border="0" alt="Hilary Duff" align="left" hspace="5" />Hilary Duff's blonde hair is "so yesterday." The 32-year-old star is celebrating Easter 2020 with a new hairstyle and hair color. On Sunday afternoon, the Lizzie...<br clear="all" />
</description>
<pubDate>Sun, 12 Apr 2020 22:23:26 GMT</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">b1139985</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>
The Disney Music Playlist You Need to Boost Your Mood Right Now
</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
https://www.eonline.com/news/1138074/the-disney-music-playlist-you-need-to-boost-your-mood-right-now?cmpid=rss-000000-rssfeed-365-topstories&utm_source=eonline&utm_medium=rssfeeds&utm_campaign=rss_topstories
]]>
</link>
<description>
<img src="https://images.eonline.com/resize/66/66//eol_images/Entire_Site/202036//rs_600x600-200406183221-600.disney_playlist_e.gif" height="66" width="66" border="0" alt="Disney Song Playlist" align="left" hspace="5" />Get ready to start smiling! It's been 25 years since Disney released A Goofy Movie on April 7, 1995, spinning off the classic anthropomorphic dog Goofy and his teenage son Max Goof...<br clear="all" />
</description>
<pubDate>Sun, 12 Apr 2020 22:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">b1138074</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>
Miley Cyrus Gives Cody Simpson a Makeover After Hair Transformation
</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
https://www.eonline.com/news/1139960/miley-cyrus-gives-cody-simpson-a-makeover-after-hair-transformation?cmpid=rss-000000-rssfeed-365-topstories&utm_source=eonline&utm_medium=rssfeeds&utm_campaign=rss_topstories
]]>
</link>
<description>
<img src="https://images.eonline.com/resize/66/66//eol_images/Entire_Site/2020312//rs_600x600-200412134919-600-miley-cyrus-cody-simpson-makeover-2-instagram-041120.jpg" height="66" width="66" border="0" alt="Miley Cyrus, Cody Simpson, Makeover, Makeup, Instagram" align="left" hspace="5" />Sure you can give your boyfriend a "quarantine haircut," but how about a makeover? Miley Cyrus gave Cody Simpson one on Saturday night as the two practiced social distancing...<br clear="all" />
</description>
<pubDate>Sun, 12 Apr 2020 21:38:35 GMT</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">b1139960</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>
Chrissy Teigen's Response to Simone Biles' Handstand Challenge Is All of Us
</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
https://www.eonline.com/news/1139961/chrissy-teigen-s-response-to-simone-biles-handstand-challenge-is-all-of-us?cmpid=rss-000000-rssfeed-365-topstories&utm_source=eonline&utm_medium=rssfeeds&utm_campaign=rss_topstories
]]>
</link>
<description>
<img src="https://images.eonline.com/resize/66/66//eol_images/Entire_Site/2019913//rs_600x600-191013151453-600-simon-biles-medals-me-101319.jpg" height="66" width="66" border="0" alt="Simone Biles" align="left" hspace="5" />Simone Biles took the handstand challenge to a whole new level. While y'all have already seen stars like Jake Gyllenhaal, Tom Holland and Harrison Osterfield partake in the handstand...<br clear="all" />
</description>
<pubDate>Sun, 12 Apr 2020 20:22:24 GMT</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">b1139961</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>
Michelle Money's Daughter Is ''Doing Well'' After Being Moved Out of the ICU
</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
https://www.eonline.com/news/1139954/michelle-money-s-daughter-is-doing-well-after-being-moved-out-of-the-icu?cmpid=rss-000000-rssfeed-365-topstories&utm_source=eonline&utm_medium=rssfeeds&utm_campaign=rss_topstories
]]>
</link>
<description>
<img src="https://images.eonline.com/resize/66/66//eol_images/Entire_Site/202031//rs_600x600-200401065121-600-Michelle-Money-ch-040120.jpg" height="66" width="66" border="0" alt="Michelle Money" align="left" hspace="5" />Ryan and Michelle Money's daughter "had a big win" with her health. The former couple has been by Brielle's side following her "terrible skateboarding accident" in...<br clear="all" />
</description>
<pubDate>Sun, 12 Apr 2020 20:00:34 GMT</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">b1139954</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>
Jessie Cast Shares Memories of Cameron Boyce During Zoom Reunion
</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
https://www.eonline.com/news/1139936/jessie-cast-shares-memories-of-cameron-boyce-during-zoom-reunion?cmpid=rss-000000-rssfeed-365-topstories&utm_source=eonline&utm_medium=rssfeeds&utm_campaign=rss_topstories
]]>
</link>
<description>
<img src="https://images.eonline.com/resize/66/66//eol_images/Entire_Site/201967//rs_600x600-190707122820-600-cameron-boyce.cm.7719.jpg" height="66" width="66" border="0" alt="Cameron Boyce, Radio Disney Awards" align="left" hspace="5" />Debby Ryan and other former stars of the Disney Channel series Jessie recently reunited on Zoom as they practice social distancing amid the coronavirus pandemic. During the video chat,...<br clear="all" />
</description>
<pubDate>Sun, 12 Apr 2020 19:41:00 GMT</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">b1139936</guid>
</item>
```

So that is the rss feed, and this is my code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;

class Blogs {
  List<BlogModel> blogs = [];

  Future<void> getBlog() async {
    String url = 'http://syndication.eonline.com/syndication/feeds/rssfeeds/topstories.xml';

    var client = http.Client();
    var response = await client.get(url);
    var rssFeed = response.body;
    var raw = xml.parse(rssFeed);
    var elements = raw.findAllElements('item');

    elements.forEach((element) {
      BlogModel blogModel = BlogModel(
        title: element.findElements('title').first.text,
        url: element.findElements('link').first.text, //This is where I want to get the link in the CDATA
        urlToImage: element.findElements('description').first.text, //This is where I want to get the image src..
        description: element.findElements('description').first.text,
      );
      blogs.add(blogModel);
    });
  }
}
```

But I do not know how to access the http string of the src in the image tag.

Also I also need to get the http String in the CDATA of the link tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should help:

```
elements.forEach((element) {

   // This will get the image's src.. since it is having problems 
   // with reading the <img>(it is considered as just text 
   // for some reason and not an xml tag).
   // I guess its due to a problem with the encoding of the rss feed
   // So reg-expression has to be used.

   final description = element.findElements('description').first.text;
   final urlRegExp = RegExp(r'(?:(?:https?):\/\/)?[\w/\-?=%.]+\.[\w/\-?=%.]+');
   final imgSrc = urlRegExp.firstMatch(description).group(0);

   // The rest of the parsing.
    BlogModel blogModel = BlogModel(
      title: element.findElements('title').first.text,
      url: element.findElements('link').first.text, //This will get the CDATA content with no problem
      urlToImage: imgSrc,
      description: element.findElements('description').first.text,
    );
    blogs.add(blogModel);
});
```

Comment: Moqbel thanks for the answer but it didnt work.. The code didn't return an error but it still didnt display the image.

Comment: E/flutter (32245): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: No element
E/flutter (32245): #0      Iterable.first (dart:core/iterable.dart:520:7)
E/flutter (32245): #1      Blogs.getBlog.<anonymous closure> (package:teens_news/helper/blogs.dart:32:53)
E/flutter (32245): #2      Iterable.forEach (dart:core/iterable.dart:279:30)
E/flutter (32245): #3      Blogs.getBlog (package:teens_news/helper/blogs.dart:27:17)

Comment: That's really strange because I have tested it and it worked perfectly. The only explanation I could think of is that maybe the xml content  you are feeding the code is not  correct. The xml file you posted had few problems I had to clean it so I striped everything and left <item> tags because it was not balanced. So that might be the reason. Are you calling an  API to get the xml content?

Comment: No Sir, am using rss feeds to get xml files from a website.. So am pretty sure the xml file is correct sir, the problem is my code, yours does not return an error so its ok, but the images are not displaying on the page. Can you please suggest another method I can use Sir.. @Moqbel

Comment: ya I tried the rss feed you have in the code and it parses well except with the img tag. I think the '<' character of  the img tag in the description section is not treated as part of an opening tag. So the the whole img tag and its content is considered as text. That's why it throws an exception. There is another way to extract the image url and that is by regular expressions. I have updated the answer take a look.

Comment: Am so so happy.. It works kinda Sir.. I wish I could send a picture of how it looks.. Thanks so much.. Please do you have any advise about the CDATA part Sir.

Comment: Well I am glad I could help :).  What about the CDATA, did it not get extracted?

Comment: About the CDATA i do not know how to extract it and get the link.. Cause i want to use the link in an onTap() widget and i do not know how to go through the CDATA tag

Comment: This line `element.findElements('link').first.text` already extra's the link by parsing the CDATA out of the box. No need to do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

i faced this problem and i tried the solution here but didn't work for me then
i found this function is useful for me.

```
String removeAllHtmlTags(String htmlText) {
RegExp exp = RegExp(
  r"<[^>]*>",
  multiLine: true,
  caseSensitive: true
);

return htmlText.replaceAll(exp, '');}
```

and this is an example:

```
 Response response = await get(
      'your_link',);
     

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var raw = XmlDocument.parse(response.body);
    var elements = raw.findAllElements("stock_available");
    productStock.addAll(elements.map((e) {
      final id = e.findElements('id').single.text;
   
      return StockAvailableProduct(
          id: int.parse(removeAllHtmlTags(id)),
          idProduct:
              removeAllHtmlTags(e.findElements('id_product').single.text),
          idProductAttribute: removeAllHtmlTags(
              e.findElements('id_product_attribute').single.text),
          idShop: removeAllHtmlTags(
              e.findElements('id_shop_group').single.text),
          
    }).toList());
  }
```